# Git branch is ahead of master

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm currently working on a massive updating project on hundreds of files within our system. My manager in charge of checking our code is having trouble pulling master files to compare to our edited local files. Git is telling him that he is 98 commits ahead of the current master, so we cannot view the files we need to compare. How can we get his master branch back to access those live files we need to compare?

Comment: Can you give step-by-step order of how your manager is pulling the master files?

Comment: If git tells him that he is "98 commits ahead" means that he has commited 98 times (one or several files) into his local master branch. 
And you cannot see those files because those commits exists only in his local repository.
He can push those changes to origin/master (the remote repository) and then you will see it. 

But are you sure that he wants to put those changes on the remote repository? Generally you push your changes to origin/master when you are sure that those changes are ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ahead of the remote, then you need to push. You have local commits that were not pushed upstream.